# Prove that if $A$ is open, then so is $A + t$, with $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have this problem I'm working on:

Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we define $$ A + t = \left\{a + t \mid a \in A \right\}. $$

> Prove that if $A$ is open, then $A + t$ is also open for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt:** Let $x \in A + t$ be arbitrary. Then $x = a + t$, with $a \in A$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $$ (x - \delta, x + \delta ) = (a + t - \delta, a + t + \delta) \subset A + t. $$ I'm having trouble finding such a $\delta$. Since it is possible that $t$ lies outside $A$, I'm not sure how to pick one. Or is there maybe a better approach in proving this statement?

Comment: HInt: what can you infer from the hypothesis that $a \in A$ and $A$ is open?

Comment: $x\mapsto x +t$ is continuous for any $t$, thus so is $x\mapsto x-t$, and thus both maps are homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

You know that since $A$ is open, there exists $\delta$ such that $(a-\delta, a+ \delta) \subset A$. The same $\delta$ works for $x \in A+t$. Can you see why?

Comment: Not really. Is it always true that if $(a - \delta, a + \delta) \subset A$, then $(a + t - \delta, a + t + \delta) \subset A + t$? Even if $t$ is a negative number, say?

Comment: Yes! Just try a few examples to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the correct way. Since $A$ is open and $a\in A$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq A$. Then $(t+a-\delta,t+a+\delta)=t+(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq t+A$.

Thus $(t+a-\delta,t+a+\delta)$ is an open conteined in $A$ centered in $t+a=x$.